# cloud run - 403 User not authorized to perform this action (PUB/SUB)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I am having a service account attached to my cloud run which has access to services like secrets and api-keys.

I have recently added a new roles like pub sub publisher and get topics and list topics to my service account. From local when i use the keyfile of the service account i am able to send data to the pub sub topic.

But when I deploy the application in cloud run which does the same job of sending messages to pub sub , the application is failing with the below error

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_batch/thread.py", line 274, in _commit response = self._client._gapic_publish( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.py", line 267, in _gapic_publish return super().publish(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/publisher/client.py", line 794, in publish response = rpc( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in **call** return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 349, in retry_wrapped_func return retry_target( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 191, in retry_target return target() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable `your text`raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 User not authorized to perform this action.

The below part is the same code which i am using locally and from cloud run application

```
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import PublisherClient
data = {"a" : 'apple',"b" : 700}
final_data = json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")
publisher_client = PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher_client.topic_path(project-id,topic-name)
future = publisher_client.publish(topic_path, final_data)
```

I can see the inherited permissions in the gcp console of the topics. The interesting part is , the cloud run is working in the lower environment. But In a different environment with the same access, the cloud run is failing. Both the environments has its own service accounts with exact same access.

Comment: Did you set the correct runtime service account on Cloud Run service? Did your service work without your PubSub addition?

Comment: yes, that is set from terraform. other services like api-key and secrets api are working fine. but even with pub sub access , i am not able to publish to pub sub from cloud run application using that service account. I am able to publish using that service account from local.

Comment: Are you sure about the topic name/path?

Answer (score 0):

I made a really silly mistake, When reading config files for pub sub alone i was reading the dev file (i missed loading environment variable so by default it pick dev). So i was trying to access a different project pub sub , this is the reason i got 403 user doesnt have access error.

Comment: That was my guess! You will be better next time ;)